# How to sum values from a column that is null?

Tags: sql, teradata, union

I need to do an union between 2 tables and there is a column on the first table that doesn't exist on the second table, so, I would like to set up a column with null's (e.g: select null as column_name from table2). However, it involves a SUM and I can't use "null as Sum(column_name)" since it doesn't work. Since the values are null, the sum would be 0.
So, how do I select a sum from a column that doesn't exist in a table but I will insert null values on that column?

Comment: Use `NVL(column_name, 0)` in your `SUM`?

Comment: You don't need a SUM, just CAST(NULL AS result_data_type). Or if you insist on having a "matching" SUM then SUM(CAST(NULL AS source_data_type))

Answer (score 1):

In your union, when you select from the table that does not have the column in question, just include `null as <column name>` in the appropriate position in your select statement. Or you could do `0 as <column name>`, whatever works better for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply ZEROIFNULL around that column to make them 0.

SUM(ZEROIFNULL(UnionColumn))  This should work fine with Teradata.

Comment: Thanks, that what I did!